# How to assign Firebase queries to an array or variable in JS and HTML

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to fetch my firebase database using a function but for some reason I cannot assign the output to a variable. Please help
I tired a for loop and pushing into an array but nothing works
I tried adding a return statement and that didn't work

My Code

```
function LeaderboardScreen(){
      InsertData();
      ReadData();
}
function ReadData(){
      const readRef = ref(db, "users/");
      onValue(readRef,(snapshot) =>{
        const data = snapshot.val();
        console.log(data)
        
        
      
      })             
    }
```

Comment: What doesn't work about the code that you shared? Is there an error message?

Comment: There isn't an error message, I can't return the variable data

Comment: "I can't" is really hard to help with. Does the `console.log(data)` show the value from the database? If no, what *does* it show and what did you expect? If yes, then can you edit the question to show the code that *doesn't* work?

Comment: It does show. I'll post the result soon